# JSON Array Targeting in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON i would like to target 'rank' of one of it's object(BTCUSD) in PHP, but the object arrangement is dynamic based on rank.

Below is the JSON output:

```
{
    "tickers":[
        {
            "pair":"BTCUSD",
            "timestamp":153900343434,
            "rank":"1",
            "bid":"1234.00",
            "ask":"1234.00"
        },
        {
            "pair":"BTCGBP",
            "timestamp":153900343434,
            "rank":"2",
            "bid":"54321.00",
            "ask":"54321.00"
        },
        {
            "pair":"BTCEUR",
            "timestamp":153900343434,
            "rank":"3",
            "bid":"54321.00",
            "ask":"54321.00"
        }
    ]
}
```

How i am currently getting the result i need:

```
$arr['RESULT'] = getJson('https://example.com/json')['tickers']['0']['rank'];
echo json_encode($arr)
```

The above code works, but it's not efficient because when a pair rank changes, it moves up in line and my code will only target the first inline and not BTCUSD pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should search the array then. You could use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

```
// Grabbing the json->tickers array
$arr = getJson('https://example.com/json')['tickers'];
// Search the array
$arr = current(array_filter($arr, function($item){
  return $item['pair'] == 'BTCUSD';
}));

echo json_encode($arr['rank']);
```

Comment: `array_filter` still returns an array. Anyway, your last line should probably read `echo json_encode($arr['RESULT']['rank']);` which, as I was saying, would echo an array, not the rank. If that's what you need go with `echo json_encode($arr['RESULT']['rank'][0]);`

Comment: You're absolutly right, changed my answer to `array_search`

Comment: Good :) the last line should be changed too anyway :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, however am getting the following error `array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given on line 6` any idea what the issue might be?